# Combining multiple rows into single row in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT distinct items.matr_code,mm_nounmodmaster.noun,mm_nounmodmaster.modifier1,mm_nounmodmaster.modifier2,mm_attributemaster.attribute, mm_templateattributes.sequence, 
mm_itemvaluemaster.itemvalue, mm_itemvaluemaster.abbrvalue, mm_templateattributes.mand_ind, mm_sourcemaster.source_code
FROM mm_items items
      INNER JOIN mm_nounmodmaster ON items.nm_code = mm_nounmodmaster.nm_code 
      INNER JOIN mm_itemattributes ON items.id = mm_itemattributes.items_id
      INNER JOIN mm_itemvaluemaster ON mm_itemattributes.itemvalmaster_id = mm_itemvaluemaster.id
      INNER JOIN mm_templateattributes ON mm_itemattributes.templateattributes_id = mm_templateattributes.id
      INNER JOIN mm_attributemaster ON mm_templateattributes.attribute = mm_attributemaster.id
      INNER JOIN mm_sourcemaster ON mm_itemattributes.source = mm_sourcemaster.id
      WHERE items.matr_code='01102027001' group by items.matr_code,mm_attributemaster.attribute, mm_templateattributes.sequence, 
mm_itemvaluemaster.itemvalue, mm_itemvaluemaster.abbrvalue, mm_templateattributes.mand_ind, mm_sourcemaster.source_code,mm_nounmodmaster.noun,mm_nounmodmaster.modifier1,mm_nounmodmaster.modifier2;
```

which gives me:

```
matr_code  |noun|mod1| mod2 |  attr  |seq | i_val | a_val  |m_ind|source

01102027001|ABRA|  --  | -- |ITEM NAME|10 | EMERY | EMERY  | Y   | --
01102027001|ABRA|  --  | -- |TYPE     |20 | --    | --     | Y   | test    
01102027001|ABRA|  --  | -- |MATERIAL |30 | --    | --     | Y   | test
01102027001|ABRA|  --  | -- |SIZE,GRIT|40 | 100   | 100    | Y   | test
01102027001|ABRA|  --  | -- |DIMENSION|50 | 280mm | 280mm  | Y   | --
01102027001|ABRA|  --  | -- |ADDITIONAL|60| DRILL | DRILL  | N   | test
```

by the above result matr_code, noun, mod1 and mod2 are same but other fields has differed, so totally 6 rows in the above result, but need the result in single row, below I have attached image for your Ref.

[image: result will be in single row]

Comment: Your image of the expected result still shows multiple rows.

Comment: This is something which should probably be handled in your presentation layer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name see the image clearly. it is in single row only i was taken the screen shot from MSExcel. Matr_code, noun,mod1 and mod2 are same data so aligned in center but other details are formated using alt+enter in single cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired result is not 1NF as you want to return a list of results within a single record (i.e. for a key `01102027001|ABRA|--|--`, you would want to get `ITEM NAME|10 | EMERY | EMERY  | Y   | --`, `TYPE     |20 | --    | --     | Y   | test`, and so on). With purely relational sql queries this is hard (or even impossible) to achieve, and it isactually very very seldom desired that way.

Relational databases (and prostgresql) can deal with NON-1NF structures, e.g. by using nested tables or XML output. However, it's probably much easier to adapt the presentation layer such that the common part  `01102027001|ABRA|--|--` is printed just once.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using `DISTINCT ON (matr_code, mod1, mod2)` instead of just `DISTINCT`, and use `array_agg(column_name_here)` for all other columns that differ.

Comment: i already tried array_agg() but doesn't shown exact result as per my above post. Is there any other way?